# Display ProgressDialog while opening new Fragment and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, navigation-drawer, progressdialog

I have a Navigation Drawer that opens several Fragments, one of them executes a background task using AsyncTask to load some data, showing in the meantime a ProgressDialog.

The problem here is the ProgressDialog is "almost" not shown. I say "almost" because it is shown but for a tiny amount of time.

**What I want to achieve is:** click on the Navigation Drawer item, close Navigation Drawer, show ProgressDialog, open Fragment with AsyncTask, do background data, close ProgressDialog, see data.

**What it's doing at the moment is:** click on the Navigation Drawer item, gets frozen, close Navigation Drawer, show & dismiss ProgressDialog very fast, see data.

I don't know why it's doing this, for sure is something I don't get. Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        // ...
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.history_menu_item)
    protected void historyMenuItemClick() {
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.history_fragment_crossing_call_log));
        progressDialog.show();

        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        switchToFragment(new HistoryFragment());
    }

    public void switchToFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

HistoryFragment:

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...

        updateCalls();

        // ...
    }

    public void updateCalls() {
        // ...

        new ShowHistoryCallLog().execute().get();

        // ...
    }

    private final class ShowHistoryCallLog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

        // ...

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {

            // ...

            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getProgressDialog();

            if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to seperate the UI and background work a bit more. I don't know if it is the best practice, but I use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to achieve that.

In the Fragment or an Activity you can register a new receiver like this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            refreshUI();
            //or
            (show/dismiss)ProgressDialog();
        }
    }, new IntentFilter("<any key>")"));
```

And if you now want to refresh your ui, you can call anywhere in your code something like that:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("<any key>"));
```

You can now register an receiver in your Fragment and in the onPreExecute of your task, just send a message to show your ProgressDialog. For dismissing the Dialog, just send a message to dismiss it in the onPostExecute. There are maybe other ways to achieve this, but this one works well for me.